# Different "SELECT" syntax in MYSQL with "dtTable.Select" in .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, sql, datatable.select

I tried "SELECT" MYSQL syntax below using MySQL Query Browser, work normally. When I used this syntax into dtTable.Select(), error is "Syntax error on expression". Please help me, Thanks.

```
Dim dtTable As DataTable = MyDataset.Tables("machine")
Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT product_name, operator_name, totalizer_name 
                                   FROM product, operator, totalizer_type, machine 
                                   WHERE product.product_id = machine.product_id AND 
                                         operator.operator_id = machine.operator_id AND 
                                         totalizer_type.totalizer_id = machine.totalizer_id 
                                   ORDER BY machine.machine_id ASC;")
Dim rowSearching() As DataRow
rowSearching = dtTable.Select(sql)  ' <--- (error in here - "Syntax error on expression")

If rowSearching.Length > 0 Then
   For Each dr As DataRow In rowSearching
      MessageBox.Show(CStr(dr.Item(0)) & " " & CStr(dr.Item(1)) & " " & CStr(dr.Item(2)))
   Next
End If
```

Comment: @Mike Miller, thanks. I tried to eliminate the "String.Format", still appears the error: "Syntax error: Missing operand after 'product_name' operator". :(

Answer (score 2):

`DataTable.Select` does not work like that. It just accepts a filter on it's columns with a syntax like the where clause syntax in sql.

#### Example:

```
dtTable.Select('operator_id = 1')
```

will return all rows in `dtTable` having `operator_id = 1`

#### For more informations:

[Filter syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[DataTable.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks. I want to retrieve data from multiple DataTable with Master Detail related in the dataset. How do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken in how Select works on the Datatable object, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx

You need to be using something along these lines

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim myData As New DataTable
Dim SQL As String

conn.ConnectionString = myConnString
conn.Open()

myCommand.Connection = conn
myCommand.CommandText = SQL

myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
myAdapter.Fill(myData)
```

See http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-4 for a decent tutorial.

Comment: I've created a database in mysql and then I put in the Dataset with "Fill" method from "MySQLDataAdapter". My difficulty is when I want to retrieve data from FOUR DataTable which Master Detail related in the Dataset. Relation between DataTable I have created. But when I try to do the command "rowSearching = dtTable.Select(sql)" to display some data from DataTable, I have not succeeded. Thanks